# php time returns wrong timestamp

Tags: php

why my PHP time returns wrong timestamp I compare my server, value with three other servers seem all the three servers give same result expect my server how can I solve this problem? Also, I asked the support and show them the difference in time they said no problem in our server as he said "the time is right in the server now time in my server"

`MON DEC 4 01:01:45 EST 2017`

as I know the time function must be same on all servers every where in the world

finally this the comparison between my server time and the others

> 1512407620

and other server in same moment

> 1512382397

Comment: Maybe need to set timezone.

Comment: You mean set time zone in my PHP code? 
I think time function not effect with that

Comment: Yes you got it right that we need to set `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` so your application will be accordingly to that timezone.

Comment: same problem time not effected with Timezone

Comment: After setting, you need to print current timezone which is set on server by doing `echo date_default_timezone_get();` if it returns the one you have set then some other otherwise its not setting.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan its return `America/Los_Angeles` but time still wrong

Comment: Can you update your question with your code lines. setting time zone and getting time ?

Answer (score 0):

You neet to set your timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Here is a list of all the support timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php